# java : Elasticsearch listing redundant values

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've been used to elasticsearch for quite a long time now, but the solution now I'm trying to find out is to list accurate values for a given a search string.

The code which I've written now in java :

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuiler = new BoolQueryBuilder();
            queryBuiler.must(new QueryStringQueryBuilder("tagName : *salary march*"));

SearchResponse response = esclient.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type)
                    .setQuery(queryBuiler)
                    .execute().actionGet();

SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
                    for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
                    Map map = hit.getSource();
                    System.out.println((String) map.get("tagName"));
                    list.add((String) map.get("tagName"));
                }

                list = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(list.get(i)); 
                }
```

Using this code, if search for a search string say "salary march", I want the solution for the search to be like "salary slip march 2018"

but the actual result for "salary march" lists everything in the index related to "salary".

```
salary slip march
salary slip april
SALARY SLIP NOVEMBER
NEW SALARY SLIP
```

Is it possible for a partial word search with accurate match for all the search string mentioned? That is if I search for "salary march" then I want the result to contain only "salary slip march".

Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is heppening is that you are using queryStringQuery

- This will first split the query and then search the generated tokens. and **default operator** which is **OR**

So you are getting documents which either match with *salary OR march*.

Here is the solution to it.

```
        BoolQueryBuilder queryBuiler = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        queryBuiler.must(new QueryStringQueryBuilder("tagName : *salary march*").defaultOperator(Operator.AND));

SearchResponse response = esclient.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type)
                .setQuery(queryBuiler)
                .execute().actionGet();

SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
                for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
                Map map = hit.getSource();
                System.out.println((String) map.get("tagName"));
                list.add((String) map.get("tagName"));
            }

            list = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i)); 
            }
    }
```

Moreover i thing you are not getting the basic concept of elastic search.

Query is searched upon terms indexed during ingestion.

And i think analyzer which is being applied to your this field is standard which would generate tokens

- salary
- slip
- march

And searching would occur on this and not on actual content which you indexed.

So no need to use wildcard query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and giving in a response! Never had an idea about default operators. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an AND condition in the query_string:

```
GET string/string/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "tagName",
      "query": "salary AND march"
    }
  }
}
```

It returns only "salary slip march" in your result string, because it is the only string containing both salary and march.

In Java:

```
new QueryStringQueryBuilder("tagName : salary AND march")
```